# C++ linker error when trying to build from object files made using makefile. Does not occur when I just build it

Tags: c++, makefile, g++, linker-errors

I'm trying to make a makefile for a multi-file C++ project that builds object files, then builds my application from those object files.

It works without any errors when I use the command:

```
all: src/main.cpp src/main_funcs.cpp src/menu.cpp src/logging.cpp\
src/runonce.cpp src/wordify.cpp src/vte.cpp
    g++ -Wall `pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0, vte-2.91, glib-2.0, gio-2.0`\
    -std=c++14 -o "updater" src/main.cpp src/main_funcs.cpp \
    src/logging.cpp src/menu.cpp src/runonce.cpp \
    src/wordify.cpp src/vte.cpp `pkg-config \
    --libs gtk+-3.0, vte-2.91, glib-2.0, gio-2.0` -lboost_date_time \
    -lboost_system -lpthread
```

But when I attempt to use my other makefile, I get a litany of linker errors (multiple definitions, undefined references). The relevant parts of the other makefile are:

```
IDIR = include
ODIR = obj
SRC_DIR = src

CXX = g++
CXXFLAGS = -Wall -std=c++14 \
`pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0, vte-2.91, glib-2.0, gio-2.0`

LIBS = `pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0, vte-2.91, glib-2.0, gio-2.0` \
-lboost_date_time -lboost_system -lpthread

_FILES = main.cpp main_funcs.cpp menu.cpp logging.cpp wordify.cpp \
runonce.cpp vte.cpp
FILES = $(patsubst %,$(SRC_DIR)/%,$(_FILES))

_DEPS = include.h logging.h main_funcs.h main_gtk.h menu.h runonce.h \
vte_include.h wordify.h
DEPS = $(patsubst %,$(IDIR)/%,$(_DEPS))

_OBJ = main.o main_funcs.o menu.o logging.o wordify.o runonce.o vte.o
OBJ = $(patsubst %,$(ODIR)/%,$(_OBJ))

VPATH = $(ODIR):$(IDIR)

OUT = -o $(BDIR)/update

$(ODIR)/%.o: $(FILES) $(DEPS)
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c -o $@ $< $(LIBS)

all: $(OBJ)
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(OUT) $^ $(LIBS)
```

I've tried possible solutions from similar threads. No dice. Any help would be great. I can post more stuff if I need to.

Here's the linker error:

```
obj/main_funcs.o:(.bss+0x0): multiple definition of `rank_run_count'
obj/main.o:(.bss+0x0): first defined here
obj/main_funcs.o:(.bss+0x4): multiple definition of `update_run_count'
obj/main.o:(.bss+0x4): first defined here
obj/main_funcs.o: In function `notroot(_GtkWidget*)':
main.cpp:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `notroot(_GtkWidget*)'
obj/main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x0): first defined here
obj/main_funcs.o: In function `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0x4f1): multiple definition of `main'
obj/main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x4f1): first defined here
obj/menu.o:(.bss+0x0): multiple definition of `rank_run_count'
obj/main.o:(.bss+0x0): first defined here
obj/menu.o:(.bss+0x4): multiple definition of `update_run_count'
obj/main.o:(.bss+0x4): first defined here
obj/menu.o: In function `notroot(_GtkWidget*)':
main.cpp:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `notroot(_GtkWidget*)'
obj/main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x0): first defined here
obj/menu.o: In function `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0x4f1): multiple definition of `main'
obj/main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x4f1): first defined here
obj/logging.o:(.bss+0x0): multiple definition of `rank_run_count'
obj/main.o:(.bss+0x0): first defined here
obj/logging.o:(.bss+0x4): multiple definition of `update_run_count'
obj/main.o:(.bss+0x4): first defined here
obj/logging.o: In function `notroot(_GtkWidget*)':
main.cpp:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `notroot(_GtkWidget*)'
obj/main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x0): first defined here
obj/logging.o: In function `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0x4f1): multiple definition of `main'
obj/main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x4f1): first defined here
obj/wordify.o:(.bss+0x0): multiple definition of `rank_run_count'
obj/main.o:(.bss+0x0): first defined here
obj/wordify.o:(.bss+0x4): multiple definition of `update_run_count'
obj/main.o:(.bss+0x4): first defined here
obj/wordify.o: In function `notroot(_GtkWidget*)':
main.cpp:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `notroot(_GtkWidget*)'
obj/main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x0): first defined here
obj/wordify.o: In function `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0x4f1): multiple definition of `main'
obj/main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x4f1): first defined here
obj/runonce.o:(.bss+0x0): multiple definition of `rank_run_count'
obj/main.o:(.bss+0x0): first defined here
obj/runonce.o:(.bss+0x4): multiple definition of `update_run_count'
obj/main.o:(.bss+0x4): first defined here
obj/runonce.o: In function `notroot(_GtkWidget*)':
main.cpp:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `notroot(_GtkWidget*)'
obj/main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x0): first defined here
obj/runonce.o: In function `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0x4f1): multiple definition of `main'
obj/main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x4f1): first defined here
obj/vte.o:(.bss+0x0): multiple definition of `rank_run_count'
obj/main.o:(.bss+0x0): first defined here
obj/vte.o:(.bss+0x4): multiple definition of `update_run_count'
obj/main.o:(.bss+0x4): first defined here
obj/vte.o: In function `notroot(_GtkWidget*)':
main.cpp:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `notroot(_GtkWidget*)'
obj/main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x0): first defined here
obj/vte.o: In function `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0x4f1): multiple definition of `main'
obj/main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x4f1): first defined here
obj/main.o: In function `mainwin(_GtkApplication*, void*)':
main.cpp:(.text+0x219): undefined reference to `main_menu_render()'
main.cpp:(.text+0x29d): undefined reference to `rank_callback(_GtkWidget*, void*, _GtkWidget*)'
main.cpp:(.text+0x2d4): undefined reference to `update_callback(_GtkWidget*, void*, _GtkWidget*)'
obj/main_funcs.o: In function `mainwin(_GtkApplication*, void*)':
main.cpp:(.text+0x219): undefined reference to `main_menu_render()'
main.cpp:(.text+0x29d): undefined reference to `rank_callback(_GtkWidget*, void*, _GtkWidget*)'
main.cpp:(.text+0x2d4): undefined reference to `update_callback(_GtkWidget*, void*, _GtkWidget*)'
obj/menu.o: In function `mainwin(_GtkApplication*, void*)':
main.cpp:(.text+0x219): undefined reference to `main_menu_render()'
main.cpp:(.text+0x29d): undefined reference to `rank_callback(_GtkWidget*, void*, _GtkWidget*)'
main.cpp:(.text+0x2d4): undefined reference to `update_callback(_GtkWidget*, void*, _GtkWidget*)'
obj/logging.o: In function `mainwin(_GtkApplication*, void*)':
main.cpp:(.text+0x219): undefined reference to `main_menu_render()'
main.cpp:(.text+0x29d): undefined reference to `rank_callback(_GtkWidget*, void*, _GtkWidget*)'
main.cpp:(.text+0x2d4): undefined reference to `update_callback(_GtkWidget*, void*, _GtkWidget*)'
obj/wordify.o: In function `mainwin(_GtkApplication*, void*)':
main.cpp:(.text+0x219): undefined reference to `main_menu_render()'
main.cpp:(.text+0x29d): undefined reference to `rank_callback(_GtkWidget*, void*, _GtkWidget*)'
main.cpp:(.text+0x2d4): undefined reference to `update_callback(_GtkWidget*, void*, _GtkWidget*)'
obj/runonce.o: In function `mainwin(_GtkApplication*, void*)':
main.cpp:(.text+0x219): undefined reference to `main_menu_render()'
main.cpp:(.text+0x29d): undefined reference to `rank_callback(_GtkWidget*, void*, _GtkWidget*)'
main.cpp:(.text+0x2d4): undefined reference to `update_callback(_GtkWidget*, void*, _GtkWidget*)'
obj/vte.o: In function `mainwin(_GtkApplication*, void*)':
main.cpp:(.text+0x219): undefined reference to `main_menu_render()'
main.cpp:(.text+0x29d): undefined reference to `rank_callback(_GtkWidget*, void*, _GtkWidget*)'
main.cpp:(.text+0x2d4): undefined reference to `update_callback(_GtkWidget*, void*, _GtkWidget*)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:41: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

Comment: Not sure if this is related but I'm not seeing ODIR and SRC_DIR being defined, if they are defined could you include them in case it is relevant.

Comment: Can you please paste also error?

Comment: C is not C++ is not C!

Comment: I will post the error, yes. And ODIR and SRC_DIR are defined. Editing now. 

Olaf, why do you say that? Is there a problem with my makefile that makes g++ think it's C?

Comment: It's a tidiness issue. Using the C tag on a C++ question screws over the people who are searching for C solutions and Vicky Versa

Comment: Commas aren't necessary in the arguments to `pkg-config`. I'm actually surprised they even work.

Comment: Oh, my bad. I didn't mean to put the C tag on it! Looks like it got removed.

Comment: I removed the commas in the pkg-config call and made it a single expansion like you suggested, Etan. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `$(ODIR)/%.o: $(FILES) $(DEPS)` rule is **wildly** wrong.

You are telling make that every output `.o` file depends on **every** `.cpp` and `.h` file.

Additionally, the rule for that target is only ever using `$<` which is the first prerequisite which is the first entry in `$(FILES)`.

So every single one of your output `.o` files is simply `main.cpp` compiled.

You should drop the recipe in that rule entirely and let make use its built-in `%.o: %.cpp` rule. (You'll need to update your `VPATH` stuff to tell make how to find your source files to do that though.)

Alternatively, you need to use an actual pattern rule there `$(OUT)/%.o: $(SRC)/%.cpp`, etc.

There are other inefficiencies in the makefile (not least of which is that you are having make run `pkg-config` multiple times, once each time it needs to expand `$(CXXFLAGS)` and `$(LIBS)`). But those are a bit farther out of scope.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I'm new to this. This is my first attempt at creating a makefile and one of my first C++ files, as you can tell. If it's not too much trouble, what would be a better way to do the pkg-config part and how would I fix the other inefficiencies?

Comment: A variable defined with `=` is a recursively expanded variable. That means that its contents are expanded whenever it is used. So when you put `\`pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0, vte-2.91, glib-2.0, gio-2.0\`` into a variable that isn't getting expanded at assignment time. Instead it gets expanded every time the variable is used. So for the `LIBS` variable in this case it gets called once in the `all` recipe and once for each file that matches the `$(ODIR)/%.o` recipe. A variable defined with `:=` is expanded at assignment time.

Comment: Writing out the list of files three times is also "inefficient" in a different way. For any one-to-one file mapping you can just use the source file list to generate the other lists via substitutions. Substitute `.cpp` with `.h` and substitute `.cpp` with `.o` and you get the other lists but only have to write the filenames once.